# ngFor does not show the data and cannot add the data when you click add button

Tags: angular, ngfor

I would like to display my data from a service in a list and load immediately the data when I open the site and when you click the "add" button, it will show the added data in a list. I'm using angular 7.

For now, when I click add button it shows the data from the `movies.service.ts` which does not what I expected, I prefer that it shows immediately when I open the site and when you click add button it will add the data that I have input.

Thanks for the help.

```
// from app.component.html

<app-movie-lists></app-movie-lists>    

// from appModule

import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import {FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { MoviesComponent } from './movies/movies.component';
import { MovieListsComponent } from './movie-lists/movie-lists.component';
import { MoviesService } from './movies.service';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    MoviesComponent,
    MovieListsComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule
  ],
  providers: [MoviesService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }



// from movies.service.ts  , this is the data I'd like to immediately when i open the site.

import { Movies } from './app.model';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';



export class MoviesService {
moviesChanged = new Subject<Movies[]>();

    movies: Movies[] = [
      {
            title: 'Mr & Mrs Smith',
            actors: ['Brad Pitt', 'Angelina Jolie'],
            releasedDate: '2010-03-18'
        },
        {
            title: 'Titanic',
            actors: ['Leonardo deCaprio', 'Cate Winslet'],
            releasedDate: '2008-03-20'
        }
    ];


    getMovies() {
        this.movies.slice();
    }

    addMovie(movie: Movies) {
        this.movies.push(movie);
        this.moviesChanged.next(this.movies.slice());
    }
}


// from app.model.ts

export class Movies {
    title: string;
    actors: string[];
    releasedDate: string;
}

// from movies.component.html, this is the form where I would like to input data and when you click the button add it will show the data in a lists which added from the existing preloaded data.

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(f)" #f= "ngForm">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="title">Title</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="title"
          ngModel
          name="title">
        </div>
            </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
          <div class="form-group" >
            <label for="actors">Actors</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="actors"
            ngModel
            name="actors">
          </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="releasedDate">Released Date</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="releasedDate"
              ngModel
              name="releasedDate">
            </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <button class= "btn btn-primary" type="submit">Add</button>
      </form>                   
    </div>
  </div>


// from movies.component.ts

import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Movies } from '../app.model';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
import { MoviesService } from '../movies.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-movies',
  templateUrl: './movies.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./movies.component.css']
})
export class MoviesComponent implements OnInit {

  @ViewChild('f') formData: NgForm;
  constructor(private moviesService: MoviesService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  onSubmit(form: NgForm) {
    const value = form.value;
    const newMovie = new Movies(value.title, value.actors, value.releasedDate);  // having problem in here,  it says expected 0 argument but got 3
    this.moviesService.addMovie(newMovie);
    }

  }    


// from movie-lists.component.html    

<div class="container">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
      <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-6">
              <app-movies></app-movies >
          </div>
        </div> 
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6">
              <ul class="list-group" *ngFor= "let movie of movies">
                <li class="list-group-item"  >
                 {{movie.title}}
                </li>
                <li class="list-group-item" >
                    {{movie.actors}}
                   </li>
                   <li class="list-group-item" >
                      {{movie.releasedDate}}
                     </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>         
  </div>
</div>


// from movie-lists.component.ts


import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Movies } from '../app.model';
import { MoviesService } from '../movies.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-movie-lists',
  templateUrl: './movie-lists.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./movie-lists.component.css']
})
export class MovieListsComponent implements OnInit {
movies: Movies[];
  constructor(private moviesService: MoviesService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
     this.moviesService.getMovies();
    this.moviesService.moviesChanged.subscribe(
      (movies: Movies[]) => {
    this.movies = movies;
      }
    );
  }

}
```

Comment: *it shows the data from the `movies.service.ts` which does not what I expected, I prefer that it shows immediately* – it's unclear what problem do you have, is it a performance issue (then why *data from the `movies.service.ts`* is unexpected?) or is it that you get wrong data?

Comment: preloading the data that comes from the movies.service.ts which was already solved by the great answers here about getMovies(). The only problem now is when  I input data and click add button, it shows blank list even I already created  addMovie(movie: Movies)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways to fix this (code is not tested, it might contain some compilation errors) :

1. Replace `moviesChanged = new Subject<Movies[]>()` to `moviesChanged = new BehaviorSubject<Movies[]>(this.movies)`;
   BehaviorSubject return the actual value or default value (constructor param) directly when `subscribe` is called.

[More about different `Subject`](https://medium.com/@luukgruijs/understanding-rxjs-behaviorsubject-replaysubject-and-asyncsubject-8cc061f1cfc0)

2. Another way : Change your method getMovies()

```
getMovies() : Movie[] {
    return this.movies.slice();
}
```

And when you call it : 
`this.movies = this.moviesService.getMovies();` to initialize your movies.

Answer (score 0):

There's a bit of overhead in your code. First of all, try changing

```
moviesChanged = new Subject<Movies[]>();
```

to

```
moviesChanged = new BehaviorSubject<Movies[]>(this.movies);
```

as it will provide the initial "movies" value to components subscribing to it.

Also, instead of:

```
ngOnInit() {
         this.moviesService.getMovies();
        this.moviesService.moviesChanged.subscribe(
          (movies: Movies[]) => {
        this.movies = movies;
          }
        );
      }
```

You may simply use 'async' pipe in your template:

```
<ul class="list-group" *ngFor= "let movie of moviesService.moviesChanged | async">
```

That way, you don't have to worry about unsubcribing when your component is destroyed.

Comment: BehaviorSubject constructor has a param (the initial value)

Comment: Thanks for your help @Laetitia and Y.Tarion it preloaded the data but still having problem when I input data and click add button. there is an error in: onSubmit(form: NgForm) {
    const value = form.value;
    // having problem in here,  it says expected 0 argument but got 3
    const newMovie = new Movies(value.title, value.actors, value.releasedDate);
    this.moviesService.addMovie(newMovie);
    }